# Run the "Show" Feature of "Select Elements by ID" using API Revit

Tags: revit-api, revit, revitpythonshell, pyrevit

In the User Interface Revit has a "select element by ID" which has a "Show" button.  I'm able using RPS and a custom pyrevit code to select the elements, however I'd like to give my users the ability to scan through all the views and open views where the element is visible similar to the "Show" button.  Before going through, iterating views and elements in views, I thought I'd ask if there's a direct command open in the API. Or a way to call the show ribbon command.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If I'm reading this right, You want to be able to let the users select elements in the drawing based on `ElementId`, correct?

Comment: Selection I understand, it's the open views with the element portion that is more complicated.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're asking...  Do you want to enable users to select a single (or multiple) element(s) in a drawing based on `ElementId`?  Do you want this to be limited by the `ActiveView` or work throughout the document regardless of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIDocument.ShowElements( ICollection ids);

Comment: Thanks Matt... Does that work only on the active view?

Comment: Nope- it will operate much like the show by id - it will open views to show them.

Comment: P.S. Didn't notice it was you! :)